Clarification on Apple Push Notification Service Server Certificate Update
According to Apple, all developers using APNs must update their application's Trust Store to include the new server certificate: SHA-2 Root: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority.
Our app uses OneSignal for push notifications. Does this mean OneSignal is responsible for handling this certificate update, or is there any action required on our side to ensure compatibility with the new certificate?
Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

If your app relies on OneSignal for push notifications, they handle compatibility with Apple's updated APNs Trust Store certificates, as they manage the connection to APNs for you.
Simply keep the OneSignal SDK up to date and refer to their documentation for more details: https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/ios-sdk-setup

What version of OneSignal SDK includes 'SHA-2 Root: USERTrust RSA Certification Authority' update?

@IliaSidorenko it should be done at their server side, so no sdk update is required
